# LockDown Browser on VirtualBox Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: virtualbox, wine, 19.10

**Problem:**

I am wondering if there's any method to get LockDown Browser (created by Respondus) to run properly on an Ubuntu 19.10 VM.

**Background/Attempts:**

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop on VirtualBox and fully updated it (sudo apt-get update/upgrade). Next, I downloaded and installed WINE with the latest stable build (2020-04-29). I then downloaded and installed LockDown Browser using WINE, but when I run LockDown Browser I only get a blank white screen. I did notice near the bottom right of this blank screen was an invisible button that I was able to click on which brought me to a new tab that froze the program and WINE spit out some debugging (it wasn't anything important as far as I can tell).

I gave it a couple more tries before restarting the VM to see if that changed the outcome, but no luck. I then switched over to root user using terminal (sudo -i) and managed to install WINE as root. I also ran the LockDown Browser installer as root by carefully starting up the WINE CMD and manually installing LockDown as root. Then using the same method I was able to launch LockDown Browser as root, but I got the same blank screen as before (yes I did restart and try again with the same result).

**Context and Question:**

I have read all over the internet that LockDown Browser doesn't work with VMs because it can somehow detect that. I have also read that it doesn't like WINE so it misbehaves. Now, as a growing computer scientist, I know there are ways to do almost anything, if anyone has experience with LockDown Browser on a Linux VM or knows how to get this to work, please help me out. Also, if you have information on this behavior I would love to hear how it achieves its reputation.

Comment: Never heard of it. Please provide some background information and where one should get it.

Comment: @DKBose https://web.respondus.com/he/lockdownbrowser/ It technically can't be directly downloaded since it has a unique identifier for each university that implements it.

Comment: Okay, so it's a commercial product and you want help on circumventing its restrictions? I feel you'll have better luck asking elsewhere. The question doesn't seem to be a good fit for this particular Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @DKBose I'm not necessarily looking to circumvent the program, I'm mainly seeing if it can be run in Ubuntu because I've heard that it can brick your PC and I'd rather that happen to an easily replaceable VM. Oh well, do you have any recommendations for other places to post this?